# How can SLAs guarantee over 100%

Tags: cloudflare, uptime

I was just looking through Cloudflares [plans](http://www.cloudflare.com/plans) and noticed that their Enterprises plan offers a SLA with 2500% uptime.

How is it therefore possible to offer anything above 100% uptime?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As stated on [the CloudFlare website](https://www.cloudflare.com/enterprise/):

> **2500% guarantee**
>
> This extended Service Level Agreement guarantees 100% uptime, and adds a multiplier to owed service credits resulting from any lapse: 5 times any downtime minutes and 5 times customers affected = 2500% guarantee

Seems fairly safe to say: Go marketing dept.! Make it sound nice.

Comment: Well that makes sense, does sound a lot better than 100% uptime and we reimburse you 5-fold